# Slide Tab form is not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this jQuery slide out form:

http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/

which works well in all browsers, except IE7, it gives an error on the function:

"Object doesn't support function or method"

The function line it is referring to is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(function(){
             $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
                 tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
                 pathToTabImage: 'sites/all/themes/my_theme/images/contact_tab.gif',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
                 imageHeight: '122px',                               //height of tab image
                 imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image    
                 tabLocation: 'right',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
                 speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
                 action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
                 topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
                 fixedPosition: true                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
             });
         });

</script>
```

It works on all other browsers even IE8 with some styling issues but jQuery still works. Does anyone know how I can get this functioning in IE7, the website with the example code above works find in IE so if I am using the same code how can it be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that jquery has a "Major issues with older browsers"

http://jquery.com/browser-support/